# Rails - really_create_a_version in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, vestal-versions

I'm using the Rails 3 Vestal Versions gem: https://github.com/lailsonbm/vestal_versions

I'd like to create some logic to determine if/when to create a new version on a model update. Per the specs, I did:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
    versioned :if => :really_create_a_version?

  def really_create_a_version
    Rails.logger.debug 'really_create_a_version really_create_a_version really_create_a_version really_create_a_version - START'
    record.inspect
    @note = Note.find(32)
    Rails.logger.debug 'really_create_a_version really_create_a_version really_create_a_version really_create_a_version - END'
  end

end
```

But that doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `really_create_a_version?' for #<Note:0x155c39a28>):
  app/controllers/notes_controller.rb:124:in `update'
```

Any suggestions or ideas? thxs

**UPDATE**

Conditional version creation. The versioned method now accepts :if and :unless options. Each expects a symbol representing an instance method or a proc that will be evaluated to determine whether or not to create a new version after an update. An array containing any combination of symbols and procs can also be given.
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    versioned :if => :really_create_a_version?
  end

Comment: Which vestal_versions (or fork) are you using ?

Comment: https://github.com/lailsonbm/vestal_versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your method like this

```
def really_create_a_version?
```

You are missing the trailing `?`